# Retain background border on click angular ngFor

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I'm trying to retain the blue background border that was clicked on each row of my panel that displays data for each year in row. Currently I'm able to hover on only one row irrespective of the fact that the panel is opened in multi view.

I tried to change this condition that sets blue border from

```
 [class.active]="((i+'_'+yearData.year)) == selectedMonthIndex"
```

to

```
 [class.active]="((i+'_'+yearData.year)) == selectedMonthIndex{{i}}" but not working.
```

Please find the plunker link [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/MfXci24ErPxdHEl1Au3e?p=preview)

Comment: use extra class "active " whenever panel is open and apply css border property

Comment: [class.active]="((i+'_'+yearData.year)) == selectedMonthIndex[i]" tried like this?

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón tried but not working :-(

Comment: @priya_singh  can u pls update in plunker..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated answer. You can check

[Link to answer](http://plnkr.co/edit/q0CAe4cK9RQgaR29hrnl?p=preview)

you have to change condition for active class in your template

```
<div class="col-md-1 month-hover" *ngFor="let monthData of yearData.cardData; let i = index" (click)="setClickedMonth((i+'_'+yearData.year),i1,monthData.view);" [class.active]="(((monthData.view)) == yearData.selected) && isActive[i1]">
  <ul class="col-md-12" style="list-style-type: none;line-height: 25px;">
     <li class="category-title ">
        {{monthData.view}}
      </li>
      <li class="category-value ">
         {{monthData.count}}
       </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Seems its not working as expected.Can you pls check.

Comment: Oh my bad. I checked only for one condition.

Comment: I have changed it. you can check now